# How to get sum of last 6 months depending on a parameter?

Tags: reporting-services

i'm currently working on a ssrs report. The report contains 4 parameters, only two are relevant to the question: no. 3 and no. 4. The label of parameter no. 3 are "12 periods" up to "24 periods", but the values are 12 up to 24 as integer.

This is what the report looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7jqE.png)

For example if i choose the value "13 periods" (or higher) for parameter no. 3, the query retrieves data for 13 periods (or higher) startet with the last month depending on parameter no. 4. So the data are included the report. Now the column "Sum Consumtion" should be only store the Sum of the last 12 periods regardless of the parameter value no. 3 not 13 periods (or higher). So the Result is 67 not 77.

Any idea how can i do this?

Thx for your support...

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a sample of your dataset data in particular, also show your report design including row and column groups below the main design window. I think this will be quite easy to do but without more info it's guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a calculated field.

1. Add a calculated field to your dataset. The expression would filter it to the past 12 months. So it would be something like this:

   ```
   =IIf(Fields!DateColumn.Value >= DateAdd(DateInterval.Months, -12, Parameters!EndDate.Value), Fields!ColumnToSum.Value, Nothing)
   ```
2. Now you can reference this new field in the total column. You would simply `Sum` it.

Depending on your date formats, you'll probably need to adjust the date comparison logic to meet your needs. If you don't have the `End Date` available in the report, add that first. It can be in the query or another calculated field in the report. But the idea is that you are getting a conditional sum.

Comment: @Matt Glad it helped. Please mark this as answered. Thanks.